# Clean Asp.Net Core 3 Project Won't Start; System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, access-denied

Trying to run a dotnet core 3 app out of the box just to run it for the first time doing a PacktPub.com tutorial, and the project won't run. I have the sdk for netcore 3.1.201, app is pointing to 'netcoreapp3.1', changed it to 'netcoreapp3', still no go. Getting the error that I don't have permission in the CLI, as well as the IDE (naturally, but just letting you know I tried).

my gitHub repo if you want to try yourself. I'm trying to revolutionize our dev dept from WebForms to API's then fully MVC, so please help if you can!

"https://github.com/BryantVail/Hands-On-RESTful-Web-Services-with-ASP-NETCore3_Dec19_SResca"

[Error Message from dotnet CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqnQ8.png)

[Program.cs Bare Bones 'Hello World', Nothing Changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6No5.png)

Comment: and if you elevate a command prompt? Aka run as administrator.

Comment: I ran as an administrator, it actually ended up being my firewall. I'm not sure which part of the process is actually being blocked bc the project will 'Build' just fine. But I suppose its solved, I just have to adjust my Anti-Virus. Thanks!